# Limits using derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

If a differentiable function $f(x)$ satisfies a functional rule 
$f(x) + f(x+2) + f(x+4) = 0$ for all $x$ belonging to real numbers,

Then find the value of :

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\bigl(f(x+12)\bigr)^2- f(x) f(0) - f(x+6) f(18) + \bigl(f(18)\bigr)^2}{x\left({\frac{\pi}{4} - \tan^{-1}{(1-x)}}\right)} $$

what's the method?

The answer is $32$.

Comment: If the limit goes to 1 the limit is just $(\text{something})/\frac\pi4$. Are you sure the equation is copied correctly? Also, $f(x)=0$ is a differentiable function satisfying the functional equation but the limit is obviously 0 not 32.

Comment: There is obviously a mistake in question (perhaps the book has typo). Because from the given hypotheses we can't conclude that limit is $32$. See the answer by user A s. Also the comment by @kennytm is valid.

Comment: I have corrected the question it is limit goes to 0 not 1. Please note.

Comment: Even if you change $x \to 1$ to $x \to 0$ the answer is not guaranteed to be $32$ rather the answer is equal to $2\{f'(0)\}^{2}$. Also as noted by @kennytm the function $f(x) = 0$ satisfies all the requirements of the question and then the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If dont know if the following can help you
\begin{align}
&f(x) + f(x+2) + f(x+4) = 0\hspace{1cm} (I)\\
&f(x+2) + f(x+4) + f(x+6) = 0\hspace{1cm} (II)\\
&f(x+6) + f(x+8) + f(x+10) = 0\hspace{1cm} (III)\\
&f(x+8) + f(x+10) + f(x+12) = 0\hspace{1cm} (IV)\\
&f(x+12) + f(x+14) + f(x+16) = 0\hspace{1cm} (V)\\
&f(x+14) + f(x+16) + f(x+18) = 0\hspace{1cm} (VI)\\
\end{align}
First $(I)-(II)$ gives $f(x)=f(x+6)$ In particular $f(0)=f(6)$

also $(I)-(II)+(III)-(IV)$ gives $f(x)=f(x+12)$ In particular $f(0)=f(12)$

also also $(I)-(II)+(III)-(IV)+(V)-(VI)$ gives $f(x)=f(x+18)$

etc ... etc ..
Noting that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} x\left({\frac{\pi}{4} - \tan^{-1}{(1-x)}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$. So
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \frac{\bigl(f(x+12)\bigr)^2- f(x) f(0) - f(x+6) f(18) + \bigl(f(18)\bigr)^2}{x\left({\frac{\pi}{4} - \tan^{-1}{(1-x)}}\right)}= \frac{4}{\pi} \lim \limits_{x \to 1} (f(x)+f(0))^{2}$$

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake but it is limit x goes to 0 not 1. Please note that. Also from your question it is evident that the period of function is 6.